# How do I retroactively make AutoFields that don't break django-admin?

Tags: django, postgresql, django-admin

I created the models in a Django app using `manage.py inspectdb` on an
existing postgres database. This seemed to work except that all the
primary keys were described in the models as `IntegerField`s, which made
them editable in the admin panel, and had to be hand-entered based on
knowledge of the id of the previous record. I just learned about this
after some usage by the client, so I went back to change things like

```
blog_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
```

...to...

```
blog_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
```

Now the id fields don't appear in the admin panel (good), but adding new rows
has become impossible (not good).

> IntegrityError at /admin/franklins_app/blog/add/
>
> duplicate key value violates unique constraint "blog_pkey"

What's the fix? (Bonus question: is it possible to capture the value that Django is trying to assign as the primary key for the new row?)

Comment: bonus answer: incremented keys are generally set by the database at the time of insert, so no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sequence behind the serial field which is your primary key doesn't know about the manually entered records.

Find the maximum value of the primary key:

```
SELECT MAX(<primary_key>) FROM <your_table>;
```

Then set the next value of the underlying sequence to a number greater than that:

```
SELECT SETVAL('<primary_key_seq>', <max_value_in_primary_key_plus_something_for_safety>);
```

You'll find the name of the sequence (mentioned above as `<primary_key_seq>`) using:

```
SELECT pg_get_serial_sequence('<your_table_name>', '<primary_key_column_name');
```

Comment: Worked like a champ. Thank you, Milen.